# python datetime and pandas to_datetime have different output when covering same timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp

When I try to convert timestamp, I used 2 method and their outcomes are different from each other

Method 1:

```
pd.to_datetime(1523808011.979,unit='s')  # I got Timestamp('2018-04-15 16:00:11.979000')
```

Method 2:

```
yyy=dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(1523808011.979).isoformat()  # I got '2018-04-16T00:00:11.979000'
```

Could you please help me to understand why?

Best regards,

YX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In repl which internal time is UTC the result is the same: https://repl.it/repls/IndolentBurlywoodAddons

On my local machine (UTC+2) two values differ exactly for two hours. So looks like the explanation is the timezone.

Answer (score 1):

The `fromtimestamp` returns the local time so if you're in a timezone that isn't UTC, then you'll get a different result.

You should use [`utcfromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) instead.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1523808011.979).isoformat()
'2018-04-15T16:00:11.979000'
```